# Caliburn.Micro 1.5.2 to 2.0.0 breaking changes for BootstrapperBase

Tags: c#, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'm trying to bring some projects over to Caliburn Micro 2.0.0 (CB.M) and I'm seeing silent failures of my code related to bootstrapping.

This because I need to get the executable assembly of my application in the bootstrapper.

More generally, I have noticed that when e.g. trying to write an MEFBoottrapper as described [here](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/bootstrapper), calls to `AssemblySource.Instance` will yield different results between 1.x and 2.0 versions of CB.M

Using CB.M 1.5.2, `AssemblySource.Instance` will contain the executing assembly.

Using CB.M 2.0.0, `AssemblySource.Instance` will contain the assembly in which the custom bootstrapper was defined (it is defined in a project different from the startup project), hence a dll.

The migration guidelines for going from 1.5.2 to 2.0.0 [here on the CB.M homepage](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/migrating-to-2.0.0) mention some more obvious breaking changes but nothing related to the above.

If anyone has good insight into CB.M and could comment on this or, point to a more exhaustive overview of breaking changes, that would be very useful.

Comment: Not sure why this is getting down voted.

Comment: Me neither, I can understand the quality of the initial version was not up to standard but especially the close vote reasons are very weird. The question could never have been mistaken for being related to "professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration". But hey, I learned something and I'm sure the answer might be useful for somebody some day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After careful comparison of the 1.x and 2.0 source I have found that the method:

`protected virtual IEnumerable<Assembly> SelectAssemblies()`

of `BootstrapperBase` has undergone some changes.

```
// Decompiled with JetBrains decompiler
// Type: Caliburn.Micro.BootstrapperBase
// Assembly: Caliburn.Micro, Version=1.5.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8e5891231f2ed21f
// MVID: DC6F950D-BBB2-4CAB-9754-D5C81FE2659F
// Assembly location: ..\bin\Debug\Caliburn.Micro.dll
if (Execute.InDesignMode)
  {
    AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
    Assembly assembly = Enumerable.LastOrDefault<Assembly>((IEnumerable<Assembly>) (currentDomain.GetType().GetMethod("GetAssemblies").Invoke((object) currentDomain, (object[]) null) as Assembly[] ?? new Assembly[0]), new Func<Assembly, bool>(BootstrapperBase.ContainsApplicationClass));
    if (assembly == (Assembly) null)
      return (IEnumerable<Assembly>) new Assembly[0];
    return (IEnumerable<Assembly>) new Assembly[1]
    {
      assembly
    };
  }
  else
  {
    Assembly entryAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
    if (entryAssembly == (Assembly) null)
      return (IEnumerable<Assembly>) new Assembly[0];
    return (IEnumerable<Assembly>) new Assembly[1]
    {
      entryAssembly
    };
  }
```

Whereas for 2.0 (Bootstrapper.cs):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Inherit from this class in order to customize the configuration of the framework.
    /// </summary>
    public abstract class BootstrapperBase {

    ... left out for brevity

    /// <summary>
    /// Override to tell the framework where to find assemblies to inspect for views, etc.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A list of assemblies to inspect.</returns>
    protected virtual IEnumerable<Assembly> SelectAssemblies() {
        return new[] { GetType().Assembly };
    }
```

I experienced this issue because I relied on the ability of `SelectAssemblies()` to return me the executable assembly for downstream use.

I could solve the issue (for my purposes, where I needed the exe assembly) by overriding like so:

```
protected override IEnumerable<System.Reflection.Assembly> SelectAssemblies()
{
    return new[] { Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() };
}
```

People with insight on why this method was changed by the CB.M team are always welcome to comment.

Comment: The change might be the result of moving pieces into a PCL.

Comment: Meaning that, in such a case, the concept of an executable doesn't always make sense (on WP, ...)? So only the actual assembly holding the bootstrapper should be returned, making more sense?